# Implementing RSA (not for practical use): Is there a limit to what numbers can be computed by Python (OR) Any other programming language?

Tags: python, math, cryptography, mathematical-optimization, python-cryptography

I was given an assignment at Uni where we were asked to implement RSA on the programming language of our choice. I chose Python to implement it and I did successfully implement it.

However, it works only with smaller numbers and starts falling apart when using bigger numbers.

Here is the code that computes the powers using the square and multiply algorithm.

```
def power_mod(num, power, mod):
    res = 1
    binary = bin(power)[2:]
    for digit in binary:
        if(digit == "0"):
            res = (res*res) % mod
        else:
            res = (res*res*num) % mod
    return res

def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def are_coprime(x, y):
    return gcd(x, y) == 1

def inverse(num, mod):
    if(are_coprime(num, mod) == 0):
        return -1 
    Q = 0
    R = 0
    T1 = T = 0
    T2 = 1
    A = mod
    B = num
    while(True):
        if(B!=0): 
            Q = A//B
        else: break
        R = A % B
        T = T1 - (T2*Q)
        A = B
        B = R
        T1 = T2
        T2 = T
    if(T1 > 0):
        return T1
    return T1 + mod

p = 797    # Arbitrary choice
q = 979    # Arbitrary choice
N = p*q
Phi = (p-1)*(q-1)
e = 31     # Arbitrary choice
d = inverse(e, Phi)

value = 2
x  = power_mod(value, e, N)
print("\"Encrypted\" value: " + str(x))
y = power_mod(x, d, N)
print("\"Decrypted\" value: " + str(y))
```

Which produces the output:

```
"Encrypted" value: 199872
"Decrypted" value: 235914
```

When it should, in theory return "2" as the Decrypted value.
However, the same code works for smaller values of p and q - such as 79 and 97.
This led me to search for RSA calculators online to see if it was just my code that was problematic.
[I stumbled upon this one](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/%7Epopyack/IntroCS/HW/RSAWorksheet.html) and it too started falling apart when using bigger numbers.

This has me questioning if computers can really handle numbers of that size. If they can't handle numbers that size, then how do hardware implementations efficiently compute RSA keys that are thousands of bits long?

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71932 and note that 979 isn't prime

Comment: Okay, sorry for the oversight. I changed the values of p and q:
p = 100003
q = 100001
(They are primes according to https://t5k.org/curios/index.php?start=6&stop=6)

and the output I get is 
"Encrypted" value: 2147483648
"Decrypted" value: 1001030032

Comment: I can [reproduce](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZC9DoIwFIXjehdf4aYuLUJiZTEmDia6Eh-ABaGGJgZKLUqfxYVFH8qnsSAMJnpyc3N_zrec-1NZk5dF2z5qcwpWr8lU4Qb5wilEpxlu9VEanWiLaV7KVEA1GvgfQ-QMyqvgkEs3URVw5tHKdRBuD3vsF5d1XHmjwseA--hwBnBNznWHLaHB4d-ffHQVMVBaFoaSmOyLVFtlRBYT7B1rJDjHi9G0YQzsADc-Zt_gTvwFLWOfXIZ4xpje) that with just Python's `pow`. So looks like all your unnecessary extra code is just distracting.

Comment: Note that python already provides arbitrary precision integer functions for power_mod, gcd, and inverse, so there's no reason to code those up yourself unless you want to, say for learning purposes. But even if you do, you should probably check each calculation by computing it with python and comparing the two. You'll find any bugs in your code much more quickly.

Comment: According to your link 100001 is *not* prime, and indeed it is not: 100001 = 11 * 9091.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk [More fun with ChatGPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuzE6.png).

Comment: Is that real? If so, that's gold, you should publish that.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, real, from their app.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've seen it miscount digits of numbers. Don't ask it to do any math other than simple addition and suchlike. AI's such as this will probably use a mathematical system like WolframAlpha in the future if just to double check.

Comment: I implemented the Rabin-miller test to check for primality before proceeding and the program works like a charm. Generative AI sucks.